# Python script to open ubuntu apps

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

How to write a python script to open apps in ubuntu

I tried os module but it didn't work

Comment: Do you want to start any process ?

Answer (score 0):

Two common methods to run system programs are os.system() and subprocess module.

`os.system` gets a terminal like command as parameter so you can start a background process just as in terminal

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("nautilus /tmp &")
0
```

If you want to get process output;

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(
...     "ls non_existent_file; exit 0",
...     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
...     shell=True)
'ls: non_existent_file: No such file or directory\n'
```